why switchmap is working like that conversion observable<t> to t
I'm working on an Angular project and came across a situation where switchMap seems to convert an      Observable into a boolean. Here's the code:
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.hello().subscribe((res: Observable<any>) => {
          console.log(res);
        });
    }
    
    hello(): Observable<any> {
        const deltePromise = this.delete().then((res: boolean) => {
          if (res) {
            return of(true);
          } else {
            return of(false);
          }
        });
        return from(deltePromise).pipe(
          tap((res) => console.log(res)),
          switchMap((res) => res),
          tap((res) => console.log(res)),
        );
    }
    
    delete(): Promise<any> {
        if (true) {
          return Promise.resolve(true);
        } else {
          return Promise.resolve(false);
        }
     }

The console output is:
observable
true
true

My question is: Why is switchMap converting an Observable<boolean> into a boolean? What is the behavior of switchMap in this case?

It is because on the first tap, you are returning an observable on the then block, so tap, will receive an observable.
But when you pass it to the switchMap whose job it is to switch from an outer observable( from(delete) ) to the inner observable (here it is of(true)).
So the switchMap, resolves the observable and return only the value inside.
Hence the second tap returns a boolean.

from operator will convert the promise to an observable, so there is no need for the then block as well as the switchMap, since there will be no inner observable to resolve. So you can simplify your code to.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable, of, from, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: ``,
})
export class App {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hello().subscribe((res: Observable<any>) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  hello(): Observable<any> {
    const deltePromise = this.delete();
    return from(deltePromise).pipe(tap((res) => console.log(res)));
  }

  delete(): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
